# Entity Framework DateTime column - GetDate() value Insertion

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I have a table with `DateCreated` and `DateUpdated` columns and using Entity Framework to insert/update values to the database.

I need the `DateCreated` column to get the SQL Server's `GetDate()` value on insertion only.

`DateUpdated` column value should always get updated with current `GetDate()` value on insertion and update both.

For the `DateCreated` column, I've set `StoreGeneratedPattern="Computed"` and on SQL Server table I've set default value of the column to be GetDate(), which works nicely as expected.

For the `DateUpdated` column I could not find a way to get the `GetDate()` value automatically set each time an entry is updated. This value get's set only when an entry is inserted.

Could someone shed some light on this.

Comment: Have you tried `StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity"`?

Comment: why doesn't getdate as the db default for datecreated work?  it shouldn't overwrite it if you don't update it...

Comment: I agree with DMoses - the default value is only populated on row creation.

Comment: @DMosses, Mark Stafford, Yes both of you are correct. the db default value gets set only when an entry is inserted but not updates. Actually what I wanted was a solution for the 'DateUpdated' field not for the 'DateCreated' field. It's completely my bad. I've re worded the question now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want `DateUpdated` to be set by the database, you can use a trigger to set the value to `getdate()`.  I believe EF will also get the value set by the trigger if you set `StoreGeneratedPattern="Computed"` for `DateUpdated`.

For reference, your trigger would look something like this (you'll have to update per your table's PK):

```
create trigger MyTable_UpdatedTrigger
on MyTable
for update
as
begin
    update t set DateUpdated = getdate()
    from MyTable t
        join inserted i on t.Id = i.Id
end
```